# Font Awesome 6 What is the right way to use it in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, font-awesome

Dependencies

```
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
```

Problem

I'm trying to create a custom button that takes props selecting a font awesome fa-solid icon. The [docs](https://fontawesome.com/icons/camera-web?s=solid) for React say I should be able to just do the following

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-camera-web" />
```

This however returns an error:

```
Could not find icon { prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'camera-web' }
```

If I do something simple like

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={"camera" as IconProp} /> // I'm using typescript
```

Then it works, but it's not the icon I'm trying to use, just a generic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, what has worked (although sometimes it doesn't?):

I've got this in my parent file, `App.js` -

```
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";

import { faBatteryHalf, faBatteryFull, faPrint } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

library.add(faBatteryHalf, faBatteryFull, faPrint);
```

Then, where I use one of them -

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
.
.
.
return (
  <button
   className="print-report-btn"
   onClick={() => print()}
  >
   <FontAwesomeIcon icon="print" size="1x" /> 
   Print Report
  </button>
)
```

Comment: For clarity, when I say it sometimes doesn't work... I went in today to add faScrewdriverWrench and it keeps saying 'faScrewDriverWrench' is not exported from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'.  My 'print' and battery icons are always present, as expected.

Comment: I see now, it seems that the site is outdated and doesn't explain that you have to click on the `free` filter to get the ones that actually come in the free-solid-svg package. They used to be a lot more generous with their icons.